# How to push data from html div to a MySQL database using JS and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```js
function net_total() {
  var net_total = 0;
  $('.qty').each(function() {
    var row = $(this).parent().parent();
    var price = row.find('.price').val();
    var total = price * $(this).val() - 0;
    row.find('.total').val(total);
  })
  $('.total').each(function() {
    net_total += ($(this).val() - 0);
  })
  $('.net_total').html("Total : $ " + net_total);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <b class="net_total" style="font-size:20px;"> </b>
</div>
```

We want net_total class data add in to another php varible like,how can insert dnet_total class data in to data base by php

Comment: Simple answer: using **AJAX**

Comment: how can do this please tell me

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_php.asp

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: Use one of [jQuery's Ajax methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) to send the data to PHP, then in your server-side PHP do the relevant data validation and then use an SQL insert statement as appropriate.

Comment: check my answer @ROHITKUMAR

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <b class="net_total" style="font-size:20px;"> </b>
</div>
```

### In your js.

```
  var net_total = 0;
  $('.qty').each(function() {
    var row = $(this).parent().parent();
    var price = row.find('.price').val();
    var total = price * $(this).val() - 0;
    row.find('.total').val(total);
  });
  $('.total').each(function() {
    net_total += ($(this).val() - 0);
  });
  $.ajax({
   url:test.php,
   type:'POST',
   data: {net_total: net_total},
   success: function(){
    $('.net_total').html("Total : $ " + net_total);
   },
   }); 
}
```

In your test.php file you will get net_total in `$_POST['net_total']`. You can save this in your db with insert query.

Let me know if it works or not.